# How to change css dispaly none or block using jquery with variables

Tags: jquery, css

edited : how make variables Css display block or none on jquery?
can anyone correct this code ?

example

```
var primary = true/false;
$(function()
    $("#primary").change(function()
         if(parseInt($("#primary").val())<limit) $("#primary").dispaly:block(); 
         else { $("#primary").display:none();
```

thanks 
regards

Comment: [The documentation addresses this very plainly](https://api.jquery.com/css/). If you have a specific problem when you attempt to apply the information in the documentation please share the code you're using so we can help.

Comment: sorry i have been input the code and example like my question .. thanks! can you help me with this problem or any structure this jquery?

Comment: you want the manipulation of the #primary element to hide or show the #primary element? You realize that once its hidden, there will be no way to un-hide it, correct? Is it possible you meant for maniplating #primary to hide or show some other element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the manipulation of the #primary element to hide or show the #primary element, there will be no way to un-hide it. Presumably you meant for manipulating #primary to hide or show some other element. Here is an example that would do that.

Ive used the .hide() and .show() methods as I feel they are cleaner, but if you prefer the css() method, it could be easily adapted.

```js
$(function() {

  var limit = 2;
  $("#primary").change(function() {
    let value = parseInt($(this).val());
    let action = value < limit ? 'show' : 'hide';
    $('#secondary')[action]();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="primary">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select><br>
<div id="secondary"> Some dependant section here</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you want to change the display property of the element having `id="foo"` based on the `display` variable value

You need to do something like this

```
if(display)
$('#foo').css('display','block');
else
$('#foo').css('display','none');
```

Comment: There's no need to compare to `true`. The truthiness of the expression will automatically be evaluated to determine which branch of the conditional to execute.

Comment: You can DRY this up a bit by inlining the condition in the parameters using a ternary, too, for what it's worth: `$("#foo").css("display", display ? "block" : "none")`

Comment: @coreyward That's right. I was trying to first make the answer more generic by taking into consideration the values as string as well instead of a boolean but then I dropped the idea and ended up with a simple answer. I guess, I should make the edits as suggested by you :)

Comment: how about this
var limit = true/false;
$(function(){ #header1 if true display block if false :display none

Comment: @Twinny Templates Not sure what you're trying to do here. Can you code this pseudo code into actual code to be more specific?